# Unchecked cast from String to String

Tags: java, eclipse

Original code without the cast:

```
ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
for (ListTreeNode pos : positions)
    elements.add(pos.getElement());
```

In ListTreeNode:

```
public String getElement() {
    return element;
}
```

Eclipse is telling me that it is an unchecked cast from String to String if I do:

```
elements.add((String)pos.getElement());
```

I put the cast in there because before that it was telling me that the method add(String) in the ArrayList is not applicable for the type (String). I don't get that?

Comment: That doesn't seem right.  Can you attach a screenshot or--better yet--the entire eclipse project?

Comment: I'd recommend cleaning your project.

Comment: post that as an answer and accept it. Just in case, you know, *someone else* happens to run into this problem somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse thinks there are two different String types. One could for example have a `com.example.String`. If both are `java.lang.String` and Eclipse somehow makes a distinction, there's very interesting.

Comment: Wouldn't eclipse complain because both types are incompatible. `java.lang.String` is final, so `com.example.String` can not extend `java.lang.String` neither the other way around.

Comment: good point, such casts should cause compile error. if neither are java.lang.String, then it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are they both `java.lang.String`? That is only way eclipse will complain. If not, clean the project and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check you Eclipse project for multiple inclusions of the JVM libraries. An example that would cause what you see is two projects, A and B, where B uses A and the JVM settings for B is different than the JVM settings for A. The String class that A uses B is not the same String class that B uses. Check your launcher settings as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just an IT answer :

Have you tried to turn it off and on ?

I know it seems stupid but sometimes eclipse gets "tired" and throws errors even if your code works perfectly.

Answer (score -5):

```
public class ListTree<String> {
```

That was the answer.

To clarify, I removed the generic type specifier. That was causing the problem. The code now looks like:

```
public class ListTree {
```

Comment: How does that fix the problem?